# Are these examples of personification?

Tags: personification

I have two sentences that I think use personification:

> You find your voice by **feeding your mind** with your passions.

and

> This apathetic culture that we live in is **silencing** our voices.

Am I correct about the use of personification here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Personification](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Personification):

> (Literary & Literary Critical Terms) the attribution of human characteristics to things, abstract ideas, etc, as for literary or artistic effect

The tho sentences can well fit the description of personification.

[Other personification examples.](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-personification.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, because,  words, **feeding your mind** and **silencing**, represents abstract concept , which is what personification is.